# Copy file while replacing text in it

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, file-copy, replace

I'm writing a script to publish a webapp. While copying files, I must replace a placeholder `current_date` in a file with the current date.

I would start with something like this to define the date string

```
date=`date +%Y%m%d`
```

The copy and replace part is where I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `sed`.  Here is an example:

```
sed "s/current_date/`date +%Y%m%d`/" infile > copyfile
```